# inversing a hash

Tags: perl, hash

I am wondering what's the most efficient way to invert a hash into another hash as the following :

```
{
D1 -> [ A
        B
        C
      ]
D2 ->  [ A
         B
       ]
D3 -> [ C
        A
      ]
}
```

I would like to make another hash like this

```
{
A - > [ D1
        D2
        D3
      ]

B ->  [ D1
        D2
      ]
C -> [ D1
       D3
     ]
}
```

The thing I have tried was
first : find unique terms in hash keys, (1 for loop)
second : make an hash which all those unique terms are key
third : go through each unique and each key, if its exist, add it to (2 for loops)
in sum 3 loops which I don't believe is the most efficient way

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %a = ( d1 => ['a','b','c'],
          d2 => ['a','b'],
          d3 => ['c','a'] );

my %b;

for my $k (sort keys %a) {
    push @{$b{$_}}, $k for @{$a{$k}};
}

print Dumper(\%b);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: The automatic creation of array references as values for `%b` is autovivification, no?

Comment: Mat, putting a space after the shebang is not supported on all platforms. Also, you might want to spell out that inner for-loop for clarity.

Comment: Now that you've called me out on it, I can't recall the specific circumstances. I know that my style for many years was to put a blank, and about three years ago I had to take the blank out because it was breaking something somewhere. I'll let it stew for a bit and hopefully the exact case will come back to me.

Comment: @alakaboo: I'm sure there is some obscure platform that requires the space. More importantly: Not every platform has the Perl executable in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @musiKk: there, fixed it. Run with `perl script.pl`, making sure perl is in your path. :)

Comment: @Mat: It wasn't against your code. It's just that you can always find a corner case where something doesn't work. You're providing an algorithmic solution so I wouldn't comment on stuff like the shebang.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a wonderfully unreadable double map for you:

```
map {
  my $k = $_;
  map { push( @{ $b{$_} }, $k ) } @{ $a{$_} }
} sort( keys(%a) );
```

It's more or less the same as @Mat's reply otherwise.

Comment: @mwp: Since 5.8.1 `map` has been context-aware and won't (wastefully) generate a list of items to return in void context. I still wouldn't write it this way, though.

Comment: @MichaelCarman, this is so. It's not a good way of solving the problem since it's more or less unreadable. This is why I referred to Mat's reply, which is a more readable version of the same solution.